# How to Connect to Local JNDI using WAS v8.5

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, mq, websphere-8

So I have a couple MQs set up in WASv8.5. I have tested these and they work fine, now I need to test some functionality. In order to do this I downloaded the "New" MQJExplorer and I noticed the ability to load JNDI from a context. Now since the Websphere instance is running locally can I just hook directly into the Websphere Context? I tried selecting Websphere Application Server and it gives me an address box starting with

> iiop://

I tried using...

> iiop://localhost

but that didn't work and neither did

> iiop://localhost:9064

I tried looking about iiop and I couldn't really find how to enable it on WebSphere. How can I make this work?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the port is Bootstrap Port and also you may try adding providerURL under WAS console: Environment > Naming > Name Space Binding.